# Boundedness in a linearly ordered set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a linearly ordered set and $A \subset B \subset X $

Can it happen that $A$ is bounded in $X$ but not in $B$ ?
Can it happen that $A$ is bounded in $B$ but not in $X$ ?

#### Attempt:

I think the first question is true. As for the second one, I think is true since if $A$ is bounded in $B$, then it must be bounded in $X$ and here is my argument:

Let $a \in A$ be arbitrary, then there exists $u,l \in B$ such that $l \leq a \leq u $. But since $B \subset X$, then $u,l \in X$ and so $l \leq a \leq u $ for all $a \in A $ and so $A$ is bounded in $X$.

So, my question would be how can I prove the first question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument for the second question isn’t quite right: you should not be starting with an $a\in A$ and picking $u$ and $\ell$ that bound it. Since $A$ is bounded in $B$, there are $u,\ell\in B$ such that $\ell\le a\le u$ for **all** $a\in A$. That is, there is a pair of bounds that work simultaneously for all of $A$. Then you can argue that $u,\ell\in X$, and $\ell\le a\le u$ for all $a\in A$, so $A$ is bounded in $X$.

To see the difference between having one set of bounds for the whole of $A$ and having separate bounds for each $a\in A$, note that $\Bbb Z$ isn’t bounded in $\Bbb R$, but it’s still true that for each $n\in\Bbb Z$ there are real numbers $u$ and $\ell$ such that $\ell\le n\le u$: just take $u=\ell=n$.

You’re right in thinking that $A$ can be bounded in $X$ but not in $B$, so what you need here is an example. Can you think of a bounded set of real numbers that is not bounded in itself? In order to be bounded in itself, a set has to have both a $____$ element and a $____$ element; can you fill in the blanks?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Prof. Scott. Can we take any open interval $(a,b)$ ? so that $(a,b)$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$, but how can I show that $(a,b)$ is not bounded in itself?

Comment: @Willie: You’re welcome. Yes, any open interval will work. Just note, for instance, that for any $x\in(a,b)$ we have $x<\frac12(x+b)<b$, so no $x\in(a,b)$ is an upper bound for $(a,b)$. (And of course you can do a similar thing at the other end.)